# Is the Azure virtual machine public IP address static?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

After creating a VM in Azure, there is a public IP assigned to it (the IP address can be check out under Azure portal > Virtual machine > Networking).

Is this public IP address assgined by Azure static or not?

[image]

Update:
When click the Stop button, there is a warning message "Public IP address will be lost ...".
[image]

Comment: @CharlesXu if it is dynamic, when it will change? I rebooted VM and it is still the same IP address, also could you provide relevant documentation link mentioning it is dynamic please?

Comment: When you Stop (from the portal) a VM you get the warning "IP will be lost". Rebooting will keep it, the "resource" remains allocated then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are right, which means the default IP address is dynamic. There is check box when stop VM, saying "Do you want to reserve the Public IP address?" does this mean if this is ticked, we can still keep the default IP address after VM stopped and later start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public IP address assigned by Azure is dynamic in default. The static type needs to be set manually.

**Update**

About the dynamic method for the public IP address, you can see rules when the public IP address would change like this:

> Selecting dynamic allocation method for a basic public IP address
>   resource means the IP address is not allocated at the time of the
>   resource creation. The public IP address is allocated when you
>   associate the public IP address with a virtual machine or when you
>   place the first virtual machine instance into the backend pool of a
>   basic load balancer. The IP address is released when you stop (or
>   delete) the resource. After being released from resource A, for
>   example, the IP address can be assigned to a different resource. If
>   the IP address is assigned to a different resource while resource A is
>   stopped, when you restart resource A, a different IP address is
>   assigned.

Answer (score 1):

It is based on the settings, When you are creating a new VM, you can find Under **`Settings`**, select **`Public IP address.`**

[image]

Comment: Hi, we are using different Azure version? Please check out my updated screen shot.